# PHP only shows one row reasons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image]Hey my php code on returning to ajax only returns one row, any help would be welcomed. 
PHP

```
<?php
 include "db.php";

 $letter=$_POST["letter"];



 $qry = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE title like '$letter%'";
 $res = mysql_query($qry);
 $num_row = mysql_num_rows($res);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

 if($num_row>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<tr><td>$row[title]</td><td><a href=$row[author]>$row[author]</a></td><td>$row[year]</td></tr></li>";
    }   
 }else{
    echo "No Books Found Begining with the letter $letter";
 }

?>
```

Ajax/javaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#button").click(function(){
    var letter=$("#letteroption").val();
    alert(letter);
    console.log(letter);
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"azlistscript.php",
            data:"letter="+letter,
            success:function(data){
                //var bookdata.html(data);
                $("#bookdata").append(data);
                $("#search").val("");
                }
                });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="bookdata">
              <thead>
                        <th class="tbl_left_column">Title</th>
                        <th class="tbl_left_column">Author</th>
                        <th class="tbl_left_column">Year</th>
                    </thead>
               </table>
```

The data displays correctly but it just does not show more than one row in the data base when there are my that begin with the letter H. All silly errors will be noted thank you.

Comment: What do you see when you run your SQL from the command line or a tool like phpmyadmin? Do you get more than one row?

Comment: u have a closing `</li>` at the end which perhaps not needed and also make sure <table> is there in the output and within that all TR goes.
The second thing check if the query is returning only one row ..

Comment: oh well hangon u have $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); remove that its not needed.

Comment: what do u mean @andrew

Comment: @user3061378 You'll want to do some research into sql injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

you are fetching two times.

remove that line before if statment.

```
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

use this:

```
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td>
            <td><a href='".$row['author']."'>". $row['author']."</a></td>
            <td>".$row['year']."</td>
        </tr>";
```

EDIT:

```
  if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
     {
     echo "No Books Found Begining with the letter $letter";
     }
   else{
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      .......
      ......
    }
```

EDIT2: i guess i understood you. then you need to compare with just first letter and not LIKE :

try this:

```
   $qry = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE  LEFT(title, 1) = '$letter'";
```

Comment: thats got it :D, very kind

Comment: do you see in my code it says if num_row>0 when i run the search for something i know that is not there it doesnt run the else statement, the old query still stays

Comment: @user3061378 try use that instead of your if statment , look my edit

Comment: nah that didnt help, i also have just noticed a problem when i search for a letter and it shows the books, when i do it for another letter the old search just stays there append to the end.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean , but i have some things to say. consider big letters and small letters , consider also that you look for something which start by `$letter` as you wrote in your query `like '$letter%'` , this will look in begining of words. otherwise just post your table data and show an example which word you look for.

Comment: hey i uploaded a picture to show you want i mean by it showing same information over again

Comment: do i need microskope to see your images ?

Comment: sorry, you do understand tho, e.g i click for books starting with b, then show, but i click books starting with c then show below the b book, rather than just showing the c

Comment: @user3061378 i guess i understood , check my edit2 , you need to compare with just first letter in tittle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate your data before echoing it:

```
if($num_row>0){
$response = '';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$response.="<tr><td>$row[title]</td><td><a href=$row[author]>$row[author]</a></td><td>$row[year]</td></tr></li>";
 }
echo $response;   
}
```